# MFC Error when using PSAPI

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I Have an MFC Dialog application. 
I use win7 service pack 1 32 bit, Visual Studio 2010, MFC 2008/2010.
This is a part of my dlg file

```
//getprocessDlg.cpp
        #include <psapi.h>
        // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

When i Run, it display error. That's it

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EnumProcesses@12
>   referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall
>   CgetprocessDlg::OnInitDialog(void)"
>   (?OnInitDialog@CgetprocessDlg@@MAEHXZ)    c:\Users\AnhNT\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\getprocess\getprocess\getprocessDlg.obj getprocess
>
> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _GetModuleBaseNameW@16 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CgetprocessDlg::PrintMemoryInfo(unsigned long)"
>   (?PrintMemoryInfo@CgetprocessDlg@@QAEXK@Z)    c:\Users\AnhNT\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\getprocess\getprocess\getprocessDlg.obj getprocess

I try all day but it has not work. Can somebody help me :(

Comment: You need to edit your linker settings to include psapi.lib.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: thanks :D. I will remark them to forward :D

Answer (score 2):

Add `Psapi.lib` to the list of linker dependencies.

Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies. Type Psapi.lib there.